# Set background and separate foreground color for cell in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using **openpyxl 2.3.5**.

I am writing an Excel sheet from Python and need to set a cell's background color to black and its foreground color (font color?) to white.

I know how to set the background color to white (leaving the foreground/font color):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(title='test')

ws['A1'] = 'hello world'

#define the color:
whiteFill = PatternFill(fgColor='FFFFFF', bgColor='FFFFFF', fill_type='solid')
ws['A1'].fill = whiteFill
```

This method "PatternFill" is probably for setting gradients in general. I tried changing fgColor and bgColor to white and black, respectively, but no luck.

I have been looking around for help, but most answers are for earlier versions of openpyxl and apparently a lot has changed in the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While styles have changed a lot since version 1.x, fills haven't changed that much.

In this case you need to set the foreground to black (`000000`) and the background doesn't matter because the "pattern" is solid.